# Reading a text file bottom to top in Visual basic

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio

I've got a text file with a name and a value next to it e.g.

"Toby", 1

"Sam",4

"Ethan",6

I need a way to read the last 10 lines of the file and then output the data. Any ideas would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some options for you. There are more.

```
    Dim fileContent() As String = File.ReadAllLines("D:\Temp\Sample.txt")

    '''' Option 1

    Dim counter1 As Integer = 1
    For Each name As String In fileContent.Reverse
        Debug.WriteLine(name)
        counter1 += 1

        If (counter1 >= 10) Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    '''' Option 2

    Dim fileContent2 As List(Of String) = fileContent.Reverse.ToList()
    For counter2 As Integer = 0 To 9
        Debug.WriteLine(fileContent2(counter2))
    Next

    '''' Option 3

    For counter3 As Integer = fileContent.Length - 1 To fileContent.Length - 10 Step -1
        Debug.WriteLine(fileContent(counter3))
    Next
```

Comment: `dim last10LinesOrWhatsInThere = File.ReadAllLines("[Some path]").Reverse().Take(10)`?

Comment: If I wanted to write the name and number into separate text boxes how could I do this? I'm able to place them into the same text box but not different ones

Comment: Strings have a `Split()` function that will separate the two parts. Then just put each part in to a different text box

Comment: JayV really out here clutching up with the knowledge